# Is `Nothing?` a legitimate use for expressing that type of input parameter doesn't matter for subclass?

Tags: kotlin

Let's say I have interfaces like this:

```
interface Car<T : Fuel?> {
    fun run(fuel: T)
}

interface Fuel {
    ...
}
```

The basic assumption is that there are some cars that run on `Fuel` but we acknowledge the fact, that the `Fuel` might not be required for some hypothetical perpetuum mobile, hence `Fuel?` is nullable.

Now we have these classes extending from these interfaces:

```
class PetrolCar : Car<PetrolCar.Petrol> {

    override fun run(fuel: Petrol) {
        println("\nRun the petrol car")
        fuel.burn()
    }

    class Petrol : Fuel {
        fun burn() = println("Burn some petrol")
    }
}

class ElectricCar : Car<ElectricCar.Electricity> {

    override fun run(fuel: Electricity) {
        println("\nRun the electric car")
        fuel.use()
    }

    class Electricity : Fuel {
        fun use() = println("Use some electricity")
    }
}

class PerpetuumMobile : Car<Nothing?> {

    override fun run(fuel: Nothing?) {
        println("\nRun the perpetuum mobile")
    }

}
```

As you would expect, when you `run` every car, the output will look like this.

```
Run the petrol car
Burn some petrol

Run the electric car
Use some electricity

Run the perpetuum mobile
```

---

**This works. But I'm not 100% comfortable with this construction. Is it a legitimate use for `Nothing?`? Is there a better alternative for such a construction?**

Comment: My suggestion would be to use a custom object, like `object NoFuel`. With `Nothing?` you're either keeping a const `val noFuel = null` somewhere or just passing a suspicious `null` in your call to `run`. With an explicit object it all looks more readable.

Comment: `Nothing?` is a type with a single value (`null`), so that fits as al3c says.  There's one other built-in type with a single value: `Unit`, but I don't know whether that would be any better.

Comment: I somewhat simplifie the original issue. It really was about a hierarchy of very similar ViewModels, which sometimes have some input Serializable payload and sometimes don't. So maybe it's more like passing `Any?` rather than `Fuel`...